# Erorr when installing node-sass

Tags: vue.js, npm, package, node-sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to install node-sass version 4.14.1 to compatible sass-loader in Vuejs but get these errors instead, thanks for your helping me!

Or Am I missing something in installing sass-loader and node-sass in vuejs 3?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Still not working after I install python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed the lastes Node.js version so everything goes wrong when I'm installing something, so I have to install the LTS version of node.js and everything is working